# What is the correct way to pass token from external server to specific api route?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, token

Right now this is how I am doing it.

I have an ajax call on client side which hits a route like "/gettoken"

When the above is called, its passed to my node server where I do a router.get("/gettoken", function etc etc), and within this, I do a router.post("url of external server i want to get token from", function etc etc), then res.json(response.token).

Then on client side in the call i made in 1) I get the response inside the .then(function(data)), i use that token received on client side to send another ajax call (yes an ajax call within an ajax call). The 2nd ajax call sends the toke to another route like "/sendtokenforapicall"

on node server side again, I use router.get("/sendtokenforapicall") and within this I do a router.post("url for external api route") and pass the token along with it to get the relevant response back

Is my flow correct? what is the correct way or better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make HTTP requests from your *server* to an *external url*, you need to use something *other than your router*. Your *router* is for **listening to incoming requests**.

To actually execute HTTP requests from your server to an URL, try using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) like this

```
var url = 'https://example.com/profile';
var data = {username: 'example'};

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

Comment: I can do fetch inside of a router.get("gettoken") on server side? Then have the fetch get the token and then send the response to client? am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You are understanding correctly. Inside your `router.get('gettoken')` you will get the request from your _client_. Then you call `fetch` to _actually_ get the token. Then you pass it as a response to the _client_

Comment: this solved my issue! I was able to pass the token on and get response for other routes. MAJOR SUCCESS! Before I leave you, I have one last question. How would one distinguish between the fact router is for listening to incoming requests and not for external? I did not catch this in the documentation. thanks!